# Modeling the effect of education on wage

Tags: regression, least-squares, econometrics, causality, instrumental-variables

I want to see that effect of education on wage. We cannot use OLS to see the causal effect of education on wage because ability is correlated with education and wage. Here I want to use an instrument variable like mother's education. But will mother's education be a good instrument variable?

The assumptions of an instrumental variable analysis are described [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5776781/). They are

1. relevance: a causal effect exists between mother's education and wage.
2. exclusion: the causal effect in 1 is mediated entirely by education.
3. exchangeability: the relation between mother's education and wage has no confounders.

The first assumption is met because if you mother has a high education then you will also likely to have a high education. But I am not sure that mother's education is uncorrelated with some variable with can affect the wage. I think a mother education will be correlated with ability because mother decision to take an education is depend on ability and ability is also correlated with the wage.

- What are the appropriate analytic and research techniques to assess the validity of mother's education as an instrument?
- Is this an appropriate approach to handling the analysis?

Comment: But ability isn't necessarily a confounder. Correlation does not imply confounding! Does education cause ability, or does ability cause education? If the first, there's no need to use instrumental variables, because there is no confounding. If the second, you could use the backdoor adjustment formula (assuming you can measure ability), or instrumental variables or the front door adjustment if you can't measure ability.